# What will the '\$' regular expression match?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have found that,

```
$ :       Matches the end of the line
\s:       Matches whitespace 
\S:       Matches any non-whitespace character
```

But what exactly does **\$** do ?

Answer (score 6):

\$ will help to find the character "$" available in the content based on the expression flags assigned to the regular expression.

Say for example:

\$: only find the single "$" in a content
\$/g: find the "$" globally available in content.

Please find the screenshot, which can give you clear idea.

\$:
[image: Expression \$]
\$ with Global expression:
[image: \$ with Global expression]

Answer (score 2):

\$ just escapes the $ character so it will match `$` literally